# Relocation error libqt5 and libpng16

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, qt5, libpng

I have recently upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 
While trying to start qjack I get this error

```
qjackctl: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: symbol png_set_option version PNG16_0 not defined in file libpng16.so.16 with link time reference
```

So I tried reinstalling qjack, all the qt5 lib and the libpng16 lib to no avail. 
So I had a deeper look at the libpng in question and checked the symbols.

```
readelf -Ws /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 | grep png_set_option
    84: 0000000000008e00    89 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 png_set_option@@PNG16_0
```

So the png_set_option is actually defined for PNG16_0 isn't it?
I don't really know what to do to correct this.

Comment: I have noticed a similar error while trying to start VLC
vlc -v
VLC media player 3.0.1 Vetinari (revision 3.0.1-0-gec0f700fcc)
[...]
[0000563928f6b7a0] main interface warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt_plugin.so' (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: symbol png_set_option version PNG16_0 not defined in file libpng16.so.16 with link time reference)

Answer (score 0):

So I located the different versions of libpng16

```
locate libpng16.so.16
/home/julien/Software/Sen2Cor-2.4.0-Linux64/lib/libpng16.so.16
/home/julien/Software/Sen2Cor-2.4.0-Linux64/lib/libpng16.so.16.25.0
/home/julien/Software/VirtualGL/libpng-1.6.0/.libs/libpng16.so.16
/home/julien/Software/VirtualGL/libpng-1.6.0/.libs/libpng16.so.16.0.0
/opt/ardour4/lib/libpng16.so.16
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16.34.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16.34.0
/usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16
/usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16.34.0
/usr/local/lib.bak/libpng16.so.16
/usr/local/lib.bak/libpng16.so.16.0.0
/usr/local/lib.bak/libpng16.so.16.34.0
```

I tried to find the lib which did not have the right symbol

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 | grep png_set_option
0000000000008e00 T png_set_option
```

This does not return anything (symbol is absent)

```
nm -D /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16 | grep png_set_option
```

So I made a symbolic link from the bad lib /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16 to the good one /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
```

Hope this help, unfortunately this can be broken when updating. Don't forget to backup /usr/local/lib/ before in case you break it

```
sudo cp -R /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib.bak
```

This solution is inspired from this [post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201453)